# Adding other elements (not ListView) to the navigation drawer with fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-fragments

I'm trying to add different views to the navigation drawer. I've created the navigation drawer using the Android Studio, it did create the navigation drawer with it's contents as a fragment, so old tutorials don't work.

Here is my main activity layout:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.app.MainActivity">

    <!-- As the main content view, the view below consumes the entire
         space available using match_parent in both dimensions. -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <!-- android:layout_gravity="start" tells DrawerLayout to treat
         this as a sliding drawer on the left side for left-to-right
         languages and on the right side for right-to-left languages.
         If you're not building against API 17 or higher, use
         android:layout_gravity="left" instead. -->
    <!-- The drawer is given a fixed width in dp and extends the full height of
         the container. -->
    <fragment android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:name="com.example.app.NavigationDrawerFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

`fragment_navigation_drawer.xml`:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer_linear">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@layout/list_divider"
        android:background="#cccc"
        android:dividerHeight="1px"
        tools:context="com.example.app.NavigationDrawerFragment"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Normally, there is no LinearLayout, I added it myself. The only thing that I've tried to change in the code generated by the studio is in NavigationDrawerFragment's onCreateView:

```
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View drawerView = inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.fragment_navigation_drawer, container, false);

        mDrawerListView = (ListView) drawerView.findViewById(R.id.navigation_drawer_list);
//        mDrawerListView = (ListView) inflater.inflate(
//                R.layout.fragment_navigation_drawer, container, false);
//      ...
```

The commented part is what was before. It works fine if I remove LinearLayout and just leave the ListView in `fragment_navigation_drawer.xml`. I have no clue what else I have to do to get it to work.

**EDIT:**

The app crashes when I'm trying to start it, here is the logcat output:

```
08-10 19:43:05.784  24162-24162/com.example.app E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.app, PID: 24162
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.app/com.example.app.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2198)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1210)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
            at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:3564)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3417)
            at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.addView(DrawerLayout.java:1406)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3393)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:759)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:290)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1937)
            at com.example.app.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:31)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5248)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1110)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2162)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1210)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Could you describe what error you are getting when you leave the listview in the linear layout?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Had to change the view that is returned by NavigationDrawerFragment.onCreateView from

```
return mDrawerListView
```

to

```
return drawerView
```

Comment: Glad you figured it out.  The "return" line wasn't in your post, so I assumed it was drawerView you were returning.  The listView already has a parent when you inflate it (the linearLayout), so when you return listView, you are actually trying to give it a second parent (the container), by making it your root view.  Hence the error you got.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. I was stuck with the same issue for almost a day.

Answer (score -1):

For change navigation drawer element on your `MainActivity.java` you must add this code :

```
drawerFragment = (FragmentDrawer) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.nav_drawer_right_sidebar_menu_fragment);
ImageView image =(ImageView) drawerFragment.getView().findViewById(R.id.imageProfile);
image.setImageResource(R.drawable.profilePicture);
drawerFragment.setUp(R.id.nav_drawer_right_sidebar_menu_fragment,(DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout), mToolbar);
drawerFragment.setDrawerListener(this);
```